# whats the ejs syntax for this jade iteration? been trying to figure out how this for loop would look in ejs

Tags: pug, ejs

block content. Jade code example below

```
h1.
    User List
ul
    each user, i in userlist
        li
            a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on few assumptions since your question does not convey full information regarding the variables

- `userList` is an array
- `i` is the index of each `user`

The iteration loop for ejs would look something like

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i< userList.length; i++) {%>
        <% user = userList[i] %>
        <li>
           <a href="mailto:<%= user.email %>">user.username</a>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Its pretty straight forward, written [here](http://www.embeddedjs.com/), in **The Template** section